# MySQL : Architecting a query reporting system

Tags: php, mysql

So I am building my first ad server, and I encountered a dilemma in the architect of the reporting system.

I batch insert to a `report` table once an hour each click and impression **separately** that was made, with timestamp by m/s as the primary key.

So basically the table looks something like that:

```
timestamp , banner, country, useragent, clicks, impressions
2015/04/24 18:00:01.312 , banner1 , US, Crhome, 1, 0
2015/04/24 18:00:02.392 , banner1 , US, Crhome, 0, 1
2015/04/24 18:00:03.122 , banner2 , CA, Firefox, 0, 1
```

When the user queries, I use `group by` that depends on the demands with `sum(impressions),sum(clicks)`

However I feel like I am doing something really wrong here. It feels like inserting each impression and each click as a new row is wrong and heavy.
I thought about making the "banner,country,useragent" as a unique index and then simply increasing click/impression on duplicate key. But, that method will ruin the timestamp accuracy, as a click on X timestamp will actually increase an earlier timestamp banner with same "banner,country,useragent" details.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag with both - actually review what a tag means before using it.

Comment: Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)